# Looking for a sample SPFX webpart (No JS Framework) with paging and styling with traditional CSS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-webparts

I just need some ideas here...
I want to build a webpart with No JS Framework selected(meaning I want to use vanilla JS)

**But I would like to use the get property configuration pane to**

- So a user can select an existing list from the current site when they edit the webpart and then i want to pass the name of the list so i can populate the div/table
  Can I achieve this using just vanilla JS or it has to be react?

Also does anyone have come across a webpart with No JS Framework to display a list with paging with custom css(no sass)?

Any links or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check samples given at: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts//tree/main/samples/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ganesh's suggestion, I would recommend that you take a look at [the SPFx web parts sample repository](https://aka.ms/sp-dev-fx-webparts). Try searching **by framework** and select the **JavaScript** framework.

If you don't find the sample you need, try [making a request](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Asample-request%2CHelp+wanted+%F0%9F%AA%A7&template=samplerequest.yml) and maybe someone in the community will be inspired by your request.

I hope this helps!?